# JSON - data download failed

Tags: json, download

If i try to get the the weather data in my C# Program .....
i get not the right data from the Website in s

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream data = webClient.OpenRead("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app-prod-static.warnwetter.de/v16/forecast_mosmix_K2613.json");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

i expect:

```
{
  "trend": {
    "start": 1695535200000,
    "temperature": [ 63, 162, 139, 85, 70, 181, 157, 101, 88, 188, 162, 162, 113, 113, 100, 100, 187, 187, 159, 159, 113, 113, 104, 104, 185, 185, 155, 155, 110, 110, 94, 94, 94, 170, 170, 170, 139, 139, 139, 104, 104, 104, 91, 91, 91 ],
    "temperatureStd": [ 19, 15, 13, 17, 20, 19, 16, 18, 21, 23, 19, 19, 20, 20, 22, 22, 24, 24, 21, 21, 20, 20, 22, 22, 26, 26, 22, 22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21 ],
    "precipitationProbabilityHigh": [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32767, 32767, 32767 ],
    "precipitationProbabilityLow": [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300 ]
  },
  "days": [
    {
      "stationId": null,
      "dayDate": "2023-09-20",
      "temperatureMin": 129,
      "temperatureMax": 221,
      "precipitation": 4,
      "windSpeed": 148,
      "windGust": 296,
      "windDirection": 2120,
      "sunshine": 3820,
      "sunrise": 1695186585000,
      "sunset": 1695231029000,
      "moonrise": 1695208353000,
      "moonset": 1695237696000,
      "moonPhase": 1,
      "icon": null,
      "icon1": 2,
      "icon2": 2
    },
    {
      "stationId": null,
      "dayDate": "2023-09-21",
      "temperatureMin": 113,
      "temperatureMax": 208,
      "precipitation": 50,
      "windSpeed": 93,
      "windGust": 259,
      "windDirection": 2020,
      "sunshine": 2020,
      "sunrise": 1695273076000,
      "sunset": 1695317296000,
      "moonrise": 1695299435000,
      "moonset": 1695326088000,
      "moonPhase": 1,
      "icon": null,
      "icon1": 2,
      "icon2": 7
    },
    {
      "stationId": null,
      "dayDate": "2023-09-22",
      "temperatureMin": 102,
      "temperatureMax": 160,
      "precipitation": 13,
      "windSpeed": 148,
      "windGust": 352,
      "windDirection": 2210,
      "sunshine": 2270,
      "sunrise": 1695359566000,
      "sunset": 1695403563000,
      "moonrise": 1695390215000,
      "moonset": 1695415342000,
      "moonPhase": 1,
      "icon": null,
      "icon1": 7,
      "icon2": 3
    },
    {
      "stationId": null,
      "dayDate": "2023-09-23",
      "temperatureMin": 81,
      "temperatureMax": 164,
      "precipitation": 0,
      "windSpeed": 130,
      "windGust": 259,
      "windDirection": 2410,
      "sunshine": 3760,
      "sunrise": 1695446057000,
      "sunset": 1695489831000,
      "moonrise": 1695480314000,
      "moonset": 1695505629000,
      "moonPhase": 2,
      "icon": null,
      "icon1": 2,
      "icon2": 2
    }
  ],
  "forecast": {
    "start": 1695189600000,
    "temperature": [ 131, 205, 185, 124, 123, 199, 173, 141, 123, 155, 130, 130, 95, 95, 82, 82, 162, 162, 129, 129, 80, 80, 63, 63 ],
    "temperatureStd": [ 13, 14, 14, 12, 14, 17, 14, 12, 10, 13, 11, 11, 14, 14, 17, 17, 14, 14, 12, 12, 15, 15, 19, 19 ],
    "windDirection": [ 2320, 2120, 1740, 2270, 2630, 2020, 2050, 2270, 2210, 2210, 2100, 2100, 2170, 2170, 2270, 2270, 2410, 2410, 2150, 2150, 2080, 2080, 2210, 2210 ],
    "windGust": [ 167, 278, 222, 111, 111, 204, 204, 222, 222, 333, 278, 278, 148, 148, 167, 167, 259, 259, 222, 222, 148, 148, 148, 148 ],
    "windSpeed": [ 74, 148, 55, 37, 37, 93, 74, 93, 93, 148, 93, 93, 74, 74, 74, 74, 130, 130, 74, 74, 55, 55, 74, 74 ],
    "icon": [ 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 19, 8, 7, 7, 18, 18, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2 ],
    "precipitationTotal": [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 42, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  }
```

BUT i GET:

‹      ÿ­VÛnÛ0ý?«€HêšçÛ€
(Ð½yp[o5:Aâ +Šüû(Ê6ì8M3 `ª%ÑG¤¨÷¢ÝUÍS±x/öm¹k‹¸h-YÔéOmõ²­ve{ØUÅbéHCU°ÊkX¯@ƒ ›!+$ eð2‚à3lÌÆM¯(°@¢éÒ~=Ø‚ýŒYVËï[þÂ%¤}UÚÑ+ä%¸éxG… ¤S1" 2îw"8Óõ½:][¶ÝUõ¶nË¶Þ4w»ÍCùP¯ëöíkýû™íÔêÿ½óãò‚ß7¯‰«þÐ> ~2–@ðDOðQÿé:°:ªâ©|Û³åâÈé›¾ñ™7‡õZFnË–ý·@t£ã êbâ ?ê†=ã´³üS,mÊU±0ªx­›§ûmUñ`Bn9ì9~0ºÜ¼­yVž€ÀÎSìÍþ¹nØ
]{Wï«rœ
VB.éU]$"Æ(Ý/›ÍHu KÃÀh‚wÑ
ýwÏ¥ÌPEý˜,É„¤:°Y¹†;ªëxƒs¼qHÍyÓaÆ›Õâ"Mxã+aÆ›žò6´G<xÒÞÍx#ð8¢a¤£!;çÐéþ•7-oxŽ7sÞÀéo@—Žïê9qSâÐŸG6Z7'Îh²ŽÎGQ#œ!Î€%ƒ×ç âèZâèqœsÎðff¼MÝ
HêofJÇÒ)mÆ8mýœ¶‡êœ64™Ófµu£ÀîhÃOã”oî_6¸Lß0IÚÄáçI(å¯.¹r’Évœî<ÿ7Û)á’D›$`’!™óÝ˜t~8:›bÓŠ"(¥ïëZò.ˆ˜~È”Qr³Íix5;™%RÊ¿éoR&f‡FvT%w^ß—<?’Sráû‡"u.Àö…}Ñ¯²»Ì8¢ç¦ç
_Ió¨ˆ(ë0R¤
xžÌeŸtºÃxÆjâ¯Kod€O†|¾/¹‹ËH2kÜ5H‚¹ÅY¤¾êýjIŠÍSlº’'OP^¥g™¼ƒF¿¬&¿Ó·ÂÏM[®'Ï>HƒŠ·ºôY@ó¿{m

`

Does anyone have an idea why this is

Greetings Marcus

Comment: Looks like the reader uses the wrong encoding. Do you know what encoding the website uses? If so, make sure, that you set the encoding of the reader to the same one.